# How to create new log4net every day if service running continuously from many days

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender

I have implemented `log4net` in my windows service and it works as expected and created new file with current date as per config setting.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs\log-%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Problem here is that, if my service is running from last 2 days, so it will not create new file with current date it keep reference of 2 days older file and adding logs into older file instead of create new file for that day.
Logger code is like

```
public static class Logger
    {
        public static log4net.ILog Log { get; set; }

        static Logger()
        {
            Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(System.Reflection.MethodBase));
        }

        public static void Trace(string message)
        {
            Log.Info(message);
        }

        public static void LogException(Exception ex)
        {
            StringBuilder builer = new StringBuilder();
            builer.AppendLine("=============Exception===========");
            builer.AppendLine("Exception: {0}");
            builer.AppendLine("StackTrack: {1}");
            Log.ErrorFormat(builer.ToString(), ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

To log info into log file I am using code

```
Logger.Trace("Hello");
```

What is code level changes require for me to, create new log file every day even service/desktop application is running continuously from last many days?

Comment: [Enable internal debugging](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug) and see if it tells you something useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your configuration has both `<staticLogFileName value="false" />` and `<staticLogFileName value="true" />`, which is may explain why it's not rolling correctly.

I suggest that you remove the `<staticLogFileName value="true" />` and change the file and DatePattern as follows:

```
<file value="Logs\log-" />
...
<param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
```

With staticLogFileName false, the date string will be appended to the base file name to give e.g.:

```
Logs\log-2018-01-30.log
```

I would note however that log4net will *only* check if it needs to roll the log file when you actually log a message, so if you aren't logging frequently, it may not roll the moment the next day begins.